# How to get reference to another controller - JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Let's say I've got 3 views and 3 controllers:
`LogInController`, `LogInView`
`MainMenuController`, `MainMenuView`
`ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineController`, `ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineView`.

An `internalMedicineButtonClicked` method change my scene to another (with some other content) but in this new scene, I want to have a button which allows me to go back to MainMenu (`goBacktoMainMenuButtonClicked()` method). And here occures my problem. How am I able to get reference to MainMenuController (the one which is corresponding with fxml file, created in LogInController) to fill `setController()` method.

```
public class LogInController {

MainMenuController mainMenuController =  new MainMenuController();
@FXML
private JFXTextField logInTextField;
@FXML
private JFXButton logInButton;
@FXML
private JFXPasswordField passwordTextField;

@FXML
void logInButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    LogInDAO logInDAO = new LogInDAO();
    if(logInDAO.checkIfLoginAndPasswordIsCorrect(logInTextField.getText(),passwordTextField.getText()))
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/MainMenu.fxml"));
        Window window = logInButton.getScene().getWindow();
        Stage stage = (Stage) window;
        loader.setController(mainMenuController); // here i'm passing original controller corresponding with fmxl
        stage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
    }
    else
    {
             (...)
    }
}

}
```

MainMenuCotroller class:

```
public class MainMenuController {
ContentOfPatientTableView patientTableViewModel = new ContentOfPatientTableView();
(..)
  @FXML
    void internalMedicineButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineView.fxml"));
        Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
        Scene scene = button.getScene();
        Stage stage = (Stage) scene.getWindow();
        loader.setController(new ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineController(patientTableViewModel));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));

    }
```

And ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineController class;

```
public class ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineController {
    IPatientDAO patientDAO = new PatientDAO();
    ContentOfPatientTableView patientTableViewModel;

    public ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineController(ContentOfPatientTableView content) {
        patientTableViewModel=content;
    }
    @FXML
    public void goBacktoMainMenuButtonClicked(ActionEvent event)
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainMenuController.class.getResource("/fxml/MainMenuView.fxml");
        loader.setController(?????????); // Here if I will pass new MainController() i will create new instance, not this which is corresponding with fxml file. How am I able to refer to instance MainController created in LogInController ?
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to pass the instance of `MainMenuController` to the `ListOfPatientsInternalMedicineController` class to do this. You probably don't want to reuse an instance of a controller class when you load the FXML again, so you probably don't really want to reload the FXML. If your main controller keeps a reference to its root element, you can have a method there that just sets that root as the root of the scene. Pass the reference to the main controller to the third controller, and invoke that method when you want to go back.

Comment: Another (perhaps better?) approach is to have another model class that has something like an `ObjectProperty<Parent> currentView`. Share that model with all your controllers (you have already shown how to do this with your existing model). You can observe the value and when it changes show that view as the root of the scene; then your controllers can switch scenes simply by changing the property. Again, you would probably want to load each FXML once.

Comment: Yes, exacly I want to load each FXML once, but i still dont get it how am i able to save each created FXML loader! This ObjectProperty would be used to save only one Scene at time .

Comment: I know how to pass model and etc. but i dont get your idea how this model should be working.

Comment: I sketched the idea in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using another model to represent the current view. You could implement this along the following lines:

```
public class ViewState {

    private final ContentOfPatientTableView patientTableViewModel ;

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Parent> currentView = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

    private Parent logInView ;
    private Parent mainMenuView ;
    private Parent listOfPatientsMainMedicineView ;

    public ViewState(ContentOfPatientTableView patientTableViewModel) {
        this.patientTableViewModel = patientTableViewModel ;
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Parent> currentViewProperty() {
        return currentView.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public void showLogIn() {
        if (logInView == null) {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("/fxml/LogIn.fxml");
                loader.setController(new LogInController(this));
                logInView = loader.load();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                // fatal...
                throw new UncheckedIOException(exc);
            }
        }
        currentView.set(logInView);
    }

    public void showMainMenu() {
        // similarly...
    }

    public void showListOfPatientsMainMedicineView() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now your `LogInController` can do:

```
public class LogInController {

    private final ViewState viewState ;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField logInTextField;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton logInButton;
    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField passwordTextField;

    public LogInController(ViewState viewState) {
        this.viewState = viewState ;
    }

    @FXML
    void logInButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        LogInDAO logInDAO = new LogInDAO();
        if(logInDAO.checkIfLoginAndPasswordIsCorrect(logInTextField.getText(),passwordTextField.getText()))
        {
            viewState.showMainMenu();
        }
        else
        {
                 (...)
        }
    }

}
```

Similarly,

```
public class MainMenuController {

    private final ViewState viewState ;

    public MainMenuController(ViewState viewState) {
        this.viewState = viewState ;
    }

    @FXML
    void internalMedicineButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        viewState.showListOfPatientsMainMedicineView();
    }
}
```

and similarly for the other controller.

Note that you are instantiating each controller in `ViewState`, so just give that class access to each of the other models it may need.

Finally, you boot all this up with

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ViewState viewState = new ViewState(/* pass models here...*/);
        viewState.showLogIn();
        Scene scene = new Scene(viewState.currentViewProperty().get());
        scene.rootProperty().bind(viewState.currentViewProperty());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it make sense for me

Comment: @Michael213 Great. It probably needs some "tweaking" to get it the way you want (e.g. you might just instantiate all your other models in "view state", or conversely you could even just move all the `ViewState` code to the `Application` class). But it should give you the gist of the idea.