# JavaFX controller communication with dynamic content

Tags: javafx, fxml

Here is a general structure of a JavaFX android mobile application I am creating.
Using (AppBar or AppBarSearch these interchange dynamically) as nested controllers within Primary Application FXML.

ParentController 
 - AppBarController
 - AppBarSearchController

primary.fxml
 - appBar.fxml / appBarSearch.fxml

```
    <AnchorPane fx:id="appBarPane" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="350.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
        <children>
            <fx:include source="appbar.fxml" fx:id="appBar" /> 
    <!-- initially shows AppBar but appBarSearch can also be here after clicking search button -->
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

A button in each of the child fxml is responsible for changing between the fxml content from appBar/AppBarSearch.

The issue arises when I am dynamically change the content of the appBar to appBarSearch and back. I want the appBar menu button to communicate to the NavigationMenu to slide in and out.

I have been looking into whether I should somehow have an instance of the parentController inside the AppBarController.

I did use the following:

```
@FXML
private AppBarController appBarController; // injected via <fx:include fx:id="child" ... />

<fx:include source="appbar.fxml" fx:id="appBar" /> <- dynamically changes

//to dynamically change content in Panes
public static void setView(View view, Pane pane) {
    try {
        pane.getChildren().clear();
        pane.getChildren().setAll((Node) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource(view.getTemplate()), resources));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

    @FXML
public void initialize() {
    appBarController.setParentController(this);
}

    @FXML
private void menuButtonClick (ActionEvent event) {
    this.parentController.triggerMenu();
}
```

Initially the above works but after switching between appBarSearch and appBar it gives me a nullPointer to the parentController instance.

It may be that after switching between controllers dynamically it would not recognise the child controller.

I want the menuBtn in AppBar to open a navigationMenu so it would require to call triggerMenu() from within PrimaryController to start animations of it sliding in and out after the button in AppBar is clicked.

Comment: If you are patient, you can watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsdaZWDcdY&t=4s

Comment: There are a couple of similar questions on here, but I can't find them with a quick search right now. The basic idea is to create a model class with a property describing the currently-displayed screen. Then your main view can observe that property and update the view (transitioning the old view out and the new one in, etc), and your other views can modify the main view indirectly by setting the property. Angela Caciedo has a framework that does this: she used to have a blog on Oracle which has now gone, but there's a repo at https://github.com/acaicedo?tab=repositories and a video (above!).

Comment: The solution seems to me to be trivial. If the views can use a common controller, simply inject it into the context of `FXMLLoader`. Otherwise, retain the instance of the controller that you injected or received from `FXMLLoader` when creating the new item.

Comment: Here is another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915578/how-to-get-reference-to-another-controller-javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to the comments I was able to fix the issue and improve my understanding of how to use Controllers and included fxml.
Below is the general code I used to connect the child controllers with my primary controller and change views dynamically.

```
@FXML
private AppBarController appBarController; // injected via <fx:include fx:id="child" ... />

@FXML
private NavMenuController navMenuController; // injected via <fx:include fx:id="child" ... />

@FXML
private MainContentController mainContentController; // injected via <fx:include fx:id="child" ... />

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    appBarController.setScreenParent(this);
    navMenuController.setScreenParent(this);
    mainContentController.setScreenParent(this);
}

/**
 * Set View on a Pane Javafx component
 */
public <T extends Pane> boolean setView(View view, T pane) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(view.getTemplate()), resources);
        pane.getChildren().clear();
        pane.getChildren().setAll((Node) myLoader.load());
        ControlledScreen childController = myLoader.getController();
        childController.setScreenParent(this);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

public void setMainContentView(View view) {
    setView(view, mainContentPane);
}

public void setAppBarView(View view) {
    setView(view, appBarPane);
}

public void setNavMenuView(View view) {
    setView(view, navMenuPane);
}

public void triggerNavMenu() {
    if (navMenuPane.getTranslateX() != 0) {
        openNav.play();
        appBarController.setMenuClosedImage();
    } else {
        closeNav.setToX(-(navMenuPane.getWidth()));
        closeNav.play();
        appBarController.setMenuClosedImage();
    }
}
```